# Quickfix ftplugin inclusion guard

Tags: vim

For some reason the inclusion guard for quickfix filetype plugin doesn't works when its contents changes.

Inserting the following contents on `~/.vim/ftplugin/qf.vim`

```
if exists("b:did_ftplugin")
   finish
endif  
call input("qf.vim!")
```

the message from the `input()` can be seem after issuing `:copen`.

But despite the include guard was set from the default filetype plugin on `$VIMRUMTIME`, as shown by `:echo b:did_ftplugin` and `:1verbose setlocal stl`, issuing `:copen`, `:cold`, `:cnew` or `:helpg helpg` also causes the message to be displayed.

This happens without additional plugins and no settings other than `filetype plugin indent on`
and `set nocompatible`.

My first guess was that any command refreshing the quickfix window closes the existing buffer and opens a new one. But including the `let b:did_ftplugin = 1` after the `endif` above avoids the filetype plugin reload, as no message is displayed after the first `:copen` (but the default filetype plugin is completely skipped, as `'stl'` isn't set anymore).

What could be the difference on between the `b:did_ftplugin` set on default filetype plugin and the one set from my home dir?

Comment: Is this just out of curiosity, or are you negatively affected by this behavior?!

Comment: Actually this behavior bothers me because I like the quickfix window to span the entire window when vertical splits exists, so I include `wincmd J` on the filetype plugin. But sometimes my screen layout get messed, and I traced the cause to the repetition of `wincmd J` due to the problem with the include guard. Despite I removed it and replaced `:copen` with `:botright copen` in a number of places, this still bothers when I forgot the problem and type `:cope` or when it is opened by new plugins. So I would like to put the command back on the filetype plugin.

Comment: What about playing with QuickFixCmdPost to react only when a new quickfix list is filled ? (or incrementing a counter that will let you know when your are really dealing with a new quickfix list ?)

Comment: @LucHermitte I'm not sure if I understood your proposal. The idea of the inclusion guard in a ftplugin is to execute once, when the buffer is loaded -- if a single flag is being reset, I don't see how a counter would avoid it. About `"to react only when a new quickfix list is filled"`: I think it should react only when the quickfix window is opened, NOT changing when it is filled with new contents.

Answer (score 2):

The *quickfix window* is mainly a view (window), though (for implementation reasons) it is backed by a Vim *buffer*. When I `:cclose` a quickfix window, and then `:copen` it again, the `:ls!` command shows an incremented buffer number. I think that explains the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: I haven't noticed that before. But the problem happens _without_ closing the quickfix window. Executing `:copen`, `:ls`, `:copen` and `:ls` shows the same buffer number for the quickfix. 
Still the message from `input()` is displayed twice.

Comment: I don't know any details, but I suspect Vim is treating this in a special way. One would need to delve into the source code to know for sure...